# Need batchfile to separate & move characters and numbers in textfile

Tags: batch-file

first post here since usually I can find my solution by just using google. But this time, nope. First of, OS is Windows 7, and it definitely has to be done within a batchfile - but additional scripts is no problem, as long as it's no software which requires installation.

I get files which are always looking like this, but the values are never the same.

```
Example\Example\Example\examplefile.ext
1 0
4 16 7 5 3 9
46215
0
20689
20656
20667
6125
33585
46213
10256
20661
40189
21650
49792
31776
2101
(blank line)
(blank line)
```

the last 2 lines "(blank line)", are as a matter of fact - *blank lines*.

Now, what I need the output file to look like, is this:

```
<A:Example\Example\Example\examplefile.ext>
<B:1 0>
<C:4>
<D:16>
<E:7>
<F:5>
<G:3>
<H:9>
<I:46215>
<J:0>
<K:20689>
<L:20656>
<M:20667>
<N:6125>
<O:33585>
<P:46213>
<Q:10256>
<R:20661>
<S:40189>
<T:21650>
<U:49792>
<V:31776>
<X:2101>
```

So, thats how I need the output. All help would be very much apprieciated.

Comment: Can you give us a clue about what is going on here and what you are trying to do? Are you running a program to get that output? What program is that? What are those numbers? Where do they come from?

Comment: Did you intend for <B:1 0> to be on one line, but 4, 16, 7, 5, 3, and 9 to go on different lines? Are there always the same number of numbers on those lines? Do the number of rows ever go above the number of characters in the alphabet? Why modify this data with a batch file, if it is presumably going to be read by something a little more useful than batch later on? Personally, I would not do this in batch. There are programming languages which are much better suited for stuff like this (though, it is definitely possible to do it in batch if you prefer).

Comment: This output comes from a 3D modelviewing program wich saves a model path and additional model properties (the values). It's saved in .chr and looks like this when opened with notepad/notepad++. 

Yes, i do intend <B:1 0> to be on one line, and the rest to be separated on different lines. No, the amout of numbers variate, but there's never more than 6 per line. (exept line 3 wich has 6 units of numbers as you can see). And no, the processed output would not be used in something else than batch later on, and it has to be batch. I'm sorry if my explanation is vague.

Comment: So it is always line **3**? and it always has **6** numbers? I feel like I can come up with something, but what have you tried so far that wasn't working for you? Is it the logic of doing it, the syntax, or something else?

Comment: Here are some of the immediate questions Did you want the last character to be an X or W?  Are there ever more than 26 lines (A-Z)? Is the first line always going to be combined?

Comment: Last character, that was a mistake, supposed to be W, but that's really not an issue, does not matter at all. All values always ends up at the same line, if the is no "value" from the modelviewer, it's simply "0" but still, at the same line. If I could find a script that can replace spaces " " with "%NL%" I can pull this off. But I've tried a vbscript and "BatchSubstitute.bat" and I cant get them to work.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

### Notes

1. This will only support a file with at most 26 items. (A-Z)
2. The second line will never be separated.

### Script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
>output.txt <nul set /p "="
set "A=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (Example\Example\Example\examplefile.ext) do (
    if "!A:~0,1!" equ "B" (
        echo ^<B:%%A^>>>output.txt
        set "A=!A:~1!"
    ) else (
        for %%B in (%%A) do (
            echo ^<!A:~0,1!:%%B^>>>output.txt
            set "A=!A:~1!"
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```